# Justifying text in the indexes of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If you have the given array, how would you go about justifying the text for a given space? Lets say you need 20 characters including white spaces in every index.

Example array

```
['Hello there champ', 
 'example text', 
 'one two three'
]
```

and then the result would be justified to a given length (20 for this example)

```
['Hello  there   champ', 
 'example         text', 
 'one    two     three'
]
```

How can you do this to get the first array formatted like the second?

Comment: You mean, how would you find if an array is formatted like the second one?

Comment: When I am given a normal array like the first one, normal structure of a sentence and I need to then format it to be like the second

Comment: Just determine how many spaces are needed and add them in equal quantity to the existing spaces.

Comment: I think you should do some attempts and share those. As a kick-start, I would think about counting the words in each array item and getting the non-space length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the strings and add to all items, except the last, some spaces until the wanted length is reached.

```js
var array = ['Hello there champ', 'example text', 'one two three'],
    length = 20;

array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    var temp = a.split(' '),
        l = length - temp.join('').length;
    while (l) {
        temp.every(function (b, j, bb) {
            if (j + 1 === bb.length) {
                return;
            }
            if (l) {
                bb[j] += ' ';
                l--;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    aa[i] = temp.join('');
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it in to seperate actions, first map the array back, then split on word boundaries and trim out the spaces that are already there.

Then it's just a counting problem. Count the words and the characters, figure out how many spaces there should be, and add something to fill in the last space when there's an uneven number of spaces etc.

```js
var arr = [
    'Hello there champ',
    'example text',
    'one two three'
]

function justify(a, n) {
    return a.map( x => {
     var words  = x.split(/\b/).filter( y => y.trim().length)
        var total  = words.join('').length;
        var spaces = (n - total) / (words.length - 1);
        var fill   = new Array(Math.floor(spaces) + 1).join(" ");
        var result = words.join( fill );
        return result.length === n ? result : result.replace(/\s([^\s]*)$/, "  $1");
    });
}

console.log( justify(arr, 20) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to determine how many spaces are needed and distribute them equally to the existing gaps (spaces between words).

```js
var arr = ['Hello there champ', 'example text', 'one two three'];

var newArr = [];

arr.forEach(v => {
    var words = v.split(/\s+/);
    var needed = 20 - words.join("").length;
    var gaps = words.length - 1;
    var perGap = Math.floor(needed / gaps);
    var extra = needed - (perGap * gaps);
    var newValue = words.join(Array(perGap + 1).join(" "));
    if(extra){ // add the extra needed spaces in the last gap
        newValue = newValue.replace(new RegExp(words[words.length - 1]+"$"), Array(extra + 1).join(" ") + words[words.length - 1]);
    }
    newArr.push(newValue);
});
newArr.forEach(v => console.log(v));
```